# Aninhar tag <ul> em outra tag <ul> com foreach

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, linq

Tenho esse foreach, que fiz com a ajuda de vocês aqui no SOPT. Custei a fazer funcionar, mas funcionou. Só que eu fiz com apenas um nó. O que vou precisar é o seguinte. Tenho um nó pai, dentro desse nó pai um filho, dentro do filho um neto e assim vai. A minha model me retorna todos os campos necessários. Já tentei fazer de várias formas e todas dão erro na tag , pois diz a mensagem que não é possível aninhar tags  da forma como eu estou fazendo. Veja só, esse código abaixo, eu consigo trazer todos os motivos.

```
<ul>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
      {

         <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
              @item.Motivo
         </li>
       }
</ul>
```

Agora preciso trazer dentro desse motivo, as unidades_negocio. Esses valores ou dados vem da mesma Model, seria mais ou menos assim:

```
<ul>
    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
       @item.Unidade_Negocio
    </li>
</ul>
```

Porém, se eu coloco esse código dentro do `foreach` principal dá erro na tag `<ul>`. Mas pela minha pouca experiência, vou precisar de uma tag `<ul>` para ir posicionando a Unidade_Negocio, e mais, preciso, ao meu entender de outro foreach somente para a Unidade_Negocio. Aí eu não consigo mais andar. Esse trampo todo é porque não consegui fazer funcionar via `jquery`, porque pela minha `jquery` já traz tudo no `each`, mas não consegui montar os check's e por isso estou trabalhando direto no `cshtml(view)`.

Fiz assim conforme o colega Miguel sugeriu, mas dá erro:

```
<ul>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                        @item.Motivo
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach (var negocio in Model.Unidade_Negocio)
                            {
                                <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                    @negocio.Unidade_Negocio
                                </li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
```

O erro que dá é esse:

```
Additional information: 'object' não contém uma definição para 'Unidade_Negocio'
```

Este é minha Action com a linq. É uma linq geral.

```
public ActionResult Acao()
        {
            RupturaEntities db = new RupturaEntities();

            var monta_arvore = db.Ruptura.Where(m => m.IDMotivo != 6)  
                               .Select(rup=>

                               new MontaArvoreAcao{
                               IDRuptura = rup.IDRuptura,
                               DataRuptura = rup.DataRuptura,
                               IDMotivo = rup.IDMotivo,
                               Motivo = rup.Motivo.Motivo1,
                               IDOrigem = rup.IDOrigem,
                               CodigoPDV = rup.CodigoPDV,
                               UF  = rup.PDV.UF,
                               Cidade = rup.PDV.Cidade,
                               CnpjDescricao= rup.PDV.Cnpj + " - " + rup.PDV.Descricao,
                               Codigo_Apresentacao = rup.Codigo_Apresentacao,
                               Unidade_Negocio = rup.Apresentacao.Unidade_Negocio,
                               Franquia = rup.Apresentacao.Franquia,
                               Familia  = rup.Apresentacao.Familia,
                               Descricao = rup.Apresentacao.Descricao
                               }).ToList().Take(50);

            return View(monta_arvore);
        }
```

Assim é que está agora:

```
<ul>
                        @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {

                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                @item.Motivo
                                <ul>
                                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                        @item.Unidade_Negocio
                                        <ul>
                                            <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                                @item.Familia
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                                                        @item.Descricao
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
```

Comment: não alteres a pergunta no fim de teres uma resposta. Assim invalidas a minha e fica confuso para quem vem ler a questão pela primeira vez, alterando o problema inicial que tinhas

Comment: Essa alteração que muda o sentido da pergunta. Primeiro o erro era de estrutura do `ul`, agora é erro a percorrer o foreach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É possível que dê erro de tag, por para colocares uma `ul` dentro de outras, tens de a colocar dentro de uma `li`, ficando algo como:

```
<ul>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
         <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
              @item.Motivo
         </li>
         <li>
            <ul>
                foreach (var item2 in item.Unidade_Negocio){//aqui colocas a lista que queres percorrer, item.Unidade_Negocio a partida só terá um elemento e não dá para fazer um foreach
                    <li item-checked='false' item-expanded='false'>
                       @item2.Unidade_Negocio
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
         </li>
       }
</ul>
```

Comment: Sim, eu quando meti o `Model.Unidade_Negocio` foi a dar o exemplo... Tu é que sabes o que tens de por no foreach. Talvez até seja `item.Unidade_Negocio`. Mas não te esqueças que tem de ser uma lista

Comment: @pnet, tu quando fazes um foreach tens de ter sempre uma lista para percorrer. Se tu queres criar uma lista de dados `Unidade_Negocio` já tens de passar do controller essa lista.

Comment: Na controller a variável é do tipo List, pois na linq eu retorno um ToList() nela.

Comment: Sim, mas não tem nada a haver com isso. Por exemplo, tu estas a devolver uma lista, que será o teu Model. Agora para fazeres outro foreach tens de passar outra lista, numa viewbag por exemplo. Colocar aqui os campos do teu Model sff

Comment: Deixa-me entender. Eu terei que fazer outro LINQ para devolver a unidade_negocio? É isso? E se for, deveria fazer o mesmo para Familia e Produto? É isso?

Comment: Exacto. Coloca na pergunta o linq que estás a fazer e os dados da tua tabela sff

Comment: Diz me só uma coisa, a tua Unidade_Negocio é uma lista de dados?? Tenta dar mais detalhes de como tens as tuas tabelas.

Comment: Ela está dentro da linq principal. É um campo que a linq tráz junto com outros campos.

Comment: Quer dizer que uma Ruptura tem várias unidades de negócio, certo?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Assim: Um Motivo => Várias UN. Uma UN => Várias Famílias. Uma Familia => Vários Produtos.

Comment: E qual é o id das UN que liga com o Motivo? O Motivo é a Ruptura?

Comment: Estou chegando a conclusão que a LINQ está totalmente errada. Não posso trazer tudo da forma como está. Fiz um forma que aparentemente funcionou, mas só vem: Um MOTIVO e esse tem uma UN e essa tem uma FAMILIA e essa tem um PRODUTO. Isso está vindo de forma errada, devido a forma com a LINQ tá. Vou corrigir isso. Vou editar e postar como eu consegui fazer para que os colegas façam a crítica se está correto ou não.

Comment: Pronto, era ai que queria chegar a pouco. Tu vais ter de ter duas listas, uma para o Motivo e outra para a UN. Depois a partir daí vais comprar os id's a construir a view